# Locate rows that have the same resource key (with different .endings) and same values

Tags: sql, string

I have the following table, containing resources with either a .text or .watermark ending:

```
+-------------+-------+
| ResourceKey | Value |
+-------------+-------+
| A.Text      | Val1  |
| A.WaterMark | Val2  |
| B.Text      | Val3  |
| B.WaterMark | Val3  |
| C.Text      | Val4  |
| C.Text      | Val4  |
| D.WaterMark | Val5  |
| E.WaterMark | Val5  |
+-------------+-------+
```

I am interested in finding which resources have the same value with the ending .text as they have with the ending .watermark.

In the example above, resource B is the only one matching the description.

So far, I was able to separate the .ending from the string by using:

```
Begin Tran

DECLARE @TestResourcs TABLE 
    (ResourceKey NVARCHAR(max), 
     Value NVARCHAR(MAX)) 

INSERT INTO @TestResourcs VALUES (' A.Text  ',' Val1    '),
        ('  A.WaterMark ',' Val2    '),
        ('  B.Text  ',' Val3    '),
        ('  B.WaterMark ',' Val3    '),
        ('  C.Text  ',' Val4    '),
        ('  C.Text  ',' Val4    '),
        ('  D.WaterMark ',' Val5    '),
        ('  E.WaterMark ',' Val5    ');

SELECT TOP 1000 ResourceKey,
                PARSENAME(ResourceKey, 1) AS TextOrWatermark,
                LEFT(ResourceKey,CHARINDEX('.',ResourceKey)) AS RegKey,
                Value
       FROM @TestResourcs        

ROLLBACK
```

However, I'm not sure how to approach the 2nd part of matching the values.
Can anyone assist?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? What is your RDBMS (SQL *flavor*)?  BTW, This task presents some programming challenge only because you have denormalized table.

Comment: If you wrote any code please add it to your post by editing it (do not post code in comments)

Comment: I've edited what I've done so far

Comment: Please bring your code in sync with the sample data you posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build two sub queries, one for text and one for watermarks and then join these - something like (untested):

```
SELECT w.resource, watermark value 
FROM 
(
  SELECT 
    PARSENAME(ResourceKey, 1) AS resource, 
    Value as watermark
  FROM 
    MyTable
  WHERE
    Value like '%.watermark'
 ) w 
 JOIN
 (
  SELECT 
    PARSENAME(ResourceKey, 1) AS resource, 
    Value as txt
  FROM 
    MyTable
  WHERE
    Value like '%.text'
 ) t
 on t.resource = w.resource 
 WHERE 
   watermark = txt
```